# Trigger Send Publish Changes funtionality gives me an error

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud

Hello I have linked a triggersend to an email. Before that I have made sure that email doesn't have any error since it has AmpScript using Send email preview. However, when I click Publish Changes functionality, it is giving me an error regarding the ampscripts. My question is what is the purpose os of Publish changes in Trigger send since I can test my email send preview email studio functionality?

Comment: Can you share the code in the email? Send Preview doesnt always catch all errors.  Usually just stop and restarting the trigger is enough to commit changes, but publishing them is best practice. If you don't do these changes are not committed and the original copy willl continue to be sent

Comment: This is the error I got. A problem occurred Updating the Triggered Send.
Please contact Customer Service for additional information.
Name : Test
External Key : 441
Message :
The email ID = 12905, contained 10 validation errors. Refer to the Triggered Send Email Validation error log, ID = 1399045293

Comment: I suspect your Ampscript might have errors. Please update your question with your code

Comment: The thing we are migrating from another instance and it has been working for 3 years. All we are doing is copy and paste the code.

Comment: Ah I see. I would raise a ticket with support or wait for one of the SFMC overlords on here to come to the rescue

Comment: instead of send preview, once try using a guided send (send flow in content builder). If the email has an Ampscript error it will not send the email. Sometimes send preview will not show you the error. If an error exists copy paste that block of ampscript code in microsite/cloudpages and try to execute and check for the errors

Comment: @Einstein, If this has been working in your account for three years, I'm assuming this is built using Classic Content, rather than Content Builder. If so,  could you select the email in My Emails by selecting the checkbox to the left of the email name and then select "validate" from the page actions across the top. This validation step is part of what "Publish Changes" in your triggered send is doing and you may find more information by manually validating the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we solved it. The reason why it didn't work in the instance is because the Physical Mailing Address and Profile center in Email tool Attribute were required in the new instance. Whereas the previous weren't. We had to open ticket with SF to make them not required and it worked.